# project php native with .htaccess not working

Tags: apache

I have a old project with PHP native in ubuntu, this project have a .htaccess for the routes.

.htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d


RewriteRule \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ RouteApi.php?resource=$1 [QSA,L,END]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ RouteAvanzado.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I want entry at the project, I get the message "index of"

I tried change the permissions in the `.htaccess` file with `chmod (755,777,764, etc)` but not working

any solution? at the moment i'm using apache2